# R shiny server creating new environment for each user/session

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way for shiny server to create a new environment for each user/process to allow the use of global variables within each session but avoiding sharing across sessions?

Specifically for the use of global variables to share data between functions within server.r per session, but not sharing between sessions.

Comment: Can you explain how is this different from a scoping issue? http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: @Divi because each session is treated as the same environment in shiny despite it being a multi-user application.

Comment: The link @Divi gives clearly mentions per-session global variables, so not sure what questions you still have.

Comment: @warmoverflow no it does not. When assigning global variables from within nested functions using <<- it will populate the environment.

Comment: @warmoverflow In fact that link provides an example of HOW global variables share between sessions rather than limiting them to session only.

Comment: If the variable is defined within `shinyServer` but outside any functions, then it's a per-session global variable that can be shared across all functions. To update its value inside a reactive environment, use `<<-`.

Comment: So basically u want to multithread your `shinyapp`, u best just creating a new app per user/session

Comment: @ Port Chop That's what I'm leaning toward. Have an apache server launch a new app and redirect to the link.

Comment: I am facing the same issue @JJL mentioned. The scoping link states that **Multiple users can connect to a single session** that meaning variables will be shared in those session affecting per user the customizability of the app.